# Cannot locate rosdep definition for [geographicinfo]

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Fuerte and I would like to use the stack [geographicinfo](http://ros.org/wiki/geodesy) from one of my packages. My package itself is stored on the company's SVN, protected with user names and passwords (i.e. not a public SVN). My package is to be shared among project partners, some of which have no ROS experience. I would thus like `geographicinfo` to be installed automatically (from source or package) when anyone using my package calls rosmake. Eventually, I would like all packages on which I depend to be installed automatically.

My project partners all use Ubuntu 11.04 and ROS Fuerte. However, they use different variants of ROS, some of which shared with other projects and thus cannot be modified.

The documentation that I found said that I should simply add `<rosdep name="geographicinfo"/>` to my manifest file, but I have the impression that I have to put the URL of the stack somewhere. Otherwise, I get the following error:

```
$ rosdep install MyPackage
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
MyPackage: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [geographicinfo]
```

How do I resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52547/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Bgeographicinfo%5D/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are asking rosdep to do something it is not designed to do.  rosdep is designed to install the system dependencies of your source tree as defined by the system dependencies.  It is not designed to install other ROS packages needed by your package.  It turns out that you can misuse it like you listed above by aliasing ros packages as system dependencies.

There's another tool that could be written to do what you want.  But in the mean time you are responsible for installing your ros dependencies.  This has not been a large priority as we have rosinstall generators which will provide you with all ros sources.  Examples can be seen [in the Source install instructions.](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source)

Or if you want binary packages it's a single line to install using apt.
`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-PACKAGE1 ros-fuerte-PACKAGE2`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-01-31**:
Ok, pretty clear! I thought that rosdep was designed to install both missing packages and system dependencies.